# Converting client side rendering to server side rendering of existing react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, react-router, http-headers

My scenario is like this:

1. The user would click on my application(Let's say application1) link via another application (Let's say application2).
2. Then the applicaion2 will send the HTTP/HTTPs headers in requests forwarded by the reverse proxy, which will contain user role and some more information.
3. In the headers, I will receive user roles.
4. Depending on the role the kind of access would be determined and given to user

Now as per my research and the previously asked question there is no way to get the http request headers.
This led me to idea of converting my application to server-side rendering but the current code base is so vast that it is proving to be a huge task and I am not able to find any suitable way to do the same as my application is heavily based on the window object and browser router and few other things which are not supported by ssr.
**What is the best way to tackle this scenario? I am stuck right now , Any suggestions are most welcome**

Answer (score 0):

not sure serverside rendering is the answer.
I did something like this before but there's only one condition
same domain from both applications and listening to the local storage!
in my case, I need to pass the basket of the user (which is client-side and stored in the local storage) to another website in the same domain
for separating scope of each application I used nginx
in nginx I wrote two different configs and each one of them points to different applications.
then in the master config of the nginx I wrote a condition if path begins with /something use app2 config and for other routes use the app1 config.

then in app1 and app2 i wrote a sync function which listens to the local storage and changes of them

for example, I have the key in local storage called 'basket' and for app2 I want to use it

```
window.addEventListener('storage', handleSyncStorage);
```

so this listener would listen to the changes in the storage.
and if I want to do something on changes of the 'basket' in local storage

```
handleSyncStorage = e => {
    if(e.key === 'basket') {
       doSomethingToSyncBasket()
    }
}
```

so this function would be called when any changes happen in the storage of basket
but as i said the only condition is same domain for both applications

Comment: The thing is application that is sending me the user roles is not managed by me. It is a portal which is used to implement security acting as a middle layer, So I cannot configure anything on that side

Comment: I also had an experience like this too, an external company wanted to call send user data to us by posting it, but as you know, you can't post anything to the client-side, so I made an endpoint in our api to catch the posted data, then set a session for user and log them in and finally redirect to my front-end, I gave the endpoint to that company and asked them to call this instead of posting data directly to my front-end.
by doing this, there is no need to make your application serverside, cause only the entry point needs to be in server

Comment: well, no because it's for our service, but can you give me an example of the data that the external service is posting? and then i can make an example with php backend and an entry point for front-end to redirect to